# Exception using LUIS dialog

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am using bot framework SDK (3.8.2 / 3.8.3) and getting the following error while using the LUIS dialog with the Bot Framework Emulator.

Any idea?

**Exception:**

;HelpWhoIsWhoDetailsFromName [File of type 'text/plain']

(strangely whatever my intent is, the exception has a  ';' in front )

**Error details**

```
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog.<EnumerateHandlers>d__0.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.GetHandlersByIntent()
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.<DispatchToIntentHandler>d__9.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.<MessageReceived>d__8.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog`1.<ResumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringEventLoop`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
---End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.EventLoopDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SetAmbientThreadCulture.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.QueueDrainingDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown---

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
```

Controller Code

```
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            try
            {
               //await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new MatLuisDialog());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string ss = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }

    private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
            // Not available in all channels
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Luis Dialog

```
[Serializable]
[LuisModel("XXXXXXX-0ab19c3225cb", "XXXXXXXX582c599915aea4")] // changed the keys 
public class MatLuisDialog: LuisDialog<string>
{

    [LuisIntent("HelpWhoIsWhoDetailsFromName")]
    public async Task HelpWhoIsWhoDetailsFromName(IDialogContext context, LuisRequest result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("From");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent("")]
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisRequest result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("No intent Found");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent("Help.Greetings")]
    public async Task Greetings(IDialogContext context, LuisRequest result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Hi, Please enter your matone id, so that i can help you better.");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you add all the details of the Exception? What is the Exception type?
Because `HelpWhoIsWhoDetailsFromName [File of type 'text/plain']` is not really clear

Comment: Can you try commenting the other two intents and see if the exception is being thrown?

Comment: Yes, tried running the code with only None intent. Strangely , what ever my first LuisIntent name is , the error is that first intent name, prefixed with a ;

Comment: @Nicolas, the complete error is in the original post itself

Comment: You don't have more details on this Exception (I saw the stack trace)? Any InnerException or other things during your `catch`?

Comment: Thats pretty much it Nicolas. You can access the complete source code here  https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApGwoaF4nIJolJ8OUVXNA3MYOGwQ6w

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are using "LuisRequest" instead of "LuisResult" in your parameters for each asynchronous method. Only LuisResult works to the best of my knowledge. Change your code to this:

```
[Serializable]
[LuisModel("XXXXXXX-0ab19c3225cb", "XXXXXXXX582c599915aea4")] // changed the keys 
public class MatLuisDialog: LuisDialog<string>
{

    [LuisIntent("HelpWhoIsWhoDetailsFromName")]
    public async Task HelpWhoIsWhoDetailsFromName(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("From");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent("")]
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
    await context.PostAsync("No intent Found");
    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent("Help.Greetings")]
    public async Task Greetings(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Hi, Please enter your matone id, so that i can help you better.");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @akshay did this fix the issue? If so, could you mark this as the answer?